# Работа с шаблоном Word на C#,

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word

Есть на форме кнопка с таким кодом

```
  private void q1z_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WordDocument wordDoc = null;
        try
        {
            wordDoc = new WordDocument(pathToTemplate);
            if (q1.Checked)
            {
                wordDoc.ReplaceAllStrings(q1marks.Text, q1.Text);
            }
            else
            {
                wordDoc.SetSelectionToText(q1marks.Text);
                wordDoc.Selection.Text = q1.Text;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            if (wordDoc != null) { wordDoc.Close(); }
            MessageBox.Show("Ошибка при замене текста на метке в документе  Word. Подробности " + error.Message);
            return;
        }
        wordDoc.Visible = true;
```

и 2 текстбокса, в один я пишу метку, к примеру @@a, во втором текст, который заменит эту метку в ворде. При помощи чекбокса также можно заменить все метки одновременно своим текстом. Проблема в том что при компиляции, студия подчеркивает мне вот здесь `if (q1.Checked)`, Cheked и говорит (см. скрин)[image: скрин ошибки]

Подскажите, что это за ошибка такая и как ее убрать, в другом проекте, код такой же - и все работает?

Comment: Э, а какого именно типа ваш `q1`, вы должны типа сами догадаться?

Comment: простой стринг, обыкновенный текстбокс

Comment: Ну, а откуда у текстбокса свойство `Checked`, это ж не чекбокс?